# ASP.NET MVC , Model Class : No model or Data Context classes in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net-entity-data-model

This is my first asp.net mvc project. I used EF Database first approach , I created my database model , then when I add a controller with views using Entity Framework , the  model or Data Context classes are not shown in dropdownlist

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDJNf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use Viewbag to pass list values on your dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the solution, make sure it build successfully, and if it was created in another project other than the web project, then make sure you added reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

My DataContext was in a separate project.

I wasn't enough to add a reference to the project.  It didn't show up in the dropdown list until I added the data project to the solution.